# Python os.sytem function not excepting command

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, terminal

I have a radio station project on my raspberry pi that transmits with the following command in linux terminal.

```
sudo /home/radio-station/PI_FM/fm_transmitter/fm_transmitter -b 100  -f 87 /home/radio-station/Desktop/the-contours-do-you-love-me.wav
```

The command works. I have written the following program in python 3 that selects a song at random and uses similar commands to play it.

```
print("Activated")
import random
import os
run = True
last_song = 0
while run:
    print("Choosing song")
    song = random.randint(1,24)
    if last_song != song:
        print("Song selected")
        if song == 1:
            print("Playing Elvis Presley Jailhouse Rock")
            os.system('sudo /home/radio-station/PI_FM/fm_transmitter/fm_transmitter -b 100  -f 87  /home/radio-station/Desktop/jailhouse-rock.wav')
        if song == 2:
            print("Playing Chuck Berry Johney B Goode")
     
            os.system( "sudo /home/radio-station/PI_FM/fm_transmitter/fm_transmitter -b 100  -f 87 /home/radio-station/Desktop/Johney-be-good-chuck-berry.wav")
        if song == 3:
            print("Playing Bill Haley Rocket 88")
            os.system("sudo /home/radio-station/PI_FM/fm_transmitter/fm_transmitter -b 100  -f 87  /home/radio-station/Desktop/Bill-Haley-rocket-88.wav")
        if song == 4:
            print("Playing Jo Stafford The Stanley Steamer")
            os.system("sudo /home/radio-station/PI_FM/fm_transmitter/fm_transmitter -b 100  -f 87 /home/radio-station/Desktop/Jo-Stafford-the-stanley-steamer.wav")
        if song == 5:
            print("Playing Perry Como Route 66")
            os.system("sudo /home/radio-station/PI_FM/fm_transmitter/fm_transmitter -b 100  -f 87 /home/radio-station/Desktop/perry-como-route-66.wav")
        if song == 6:
            print("PLaying Chuck Berry Route 66")
            os.system("sudo /home/radio-station/PI_FM/fm_transmitter/fm_transmitter -b 100  -f 87 /home/radio-station/Desktop/chuck-berry-route-66.wav")
        if song == 7:
            print("PLaying Jo Stafford In My Merry Oldsmobile")
            os.system("sudo /home/radio-station/PI_FM/fm_transmitter/fm_transmitter -b 100  -f 87 /home/radio-station/Desktop/Jo-Stafford-in-my-merry-oldsmobile.wav")
        if song == 8:
            print("Playing The Chords Shboom")
            os.system("sudo /home/radio-station/PI_FM/fm_transmitter/fm_transmitter -b 100  -f 87 /home/radio-station/Desktop/the-chords-shboom.wav")
        if song == 9:
            print("Playing The Crew Cuts Shboom")
            os.system("sudo /home/radio-station/PI_FM/fm_transmitter/fm_transmitter -b 100  -f 87 /home/radio-station/Desktop/the-crew-cuts-sh-boom-sh-boom.wav")
        if song == 10:
            print("Playing Chuck Berry Carol")
            os.system("sudo /home/radio-station/PI_FM/fm_transmitter/fm_transmitter -b 100  -f 87 /home/radio-station/Desktop/Chuck-Berry-carol.wav")
        if song == 11:
            print("Playing The Contours Do you love me?")
            os.system("sudo /home/radio-station/PI_FM/fm_transmitter/fm_transmitter -b 100  -f 87 /home/radio-station/Desktop/the-contours-do-you-love-me.wav")
        if song == 12:
            print("Playing Jerry Lee Lewis Great balls of Fire")
            os.system("sudo /home/radio-station/PI_FM/fm_transmitter/fm_transmitter -b 100  -f 87 /home/radio-station/Desktop/jerry-lee-lewis-great-balls-of-fire.wav")
        if song == 13:
            print("Playing Chubby Checker The twist")
            os.system("sudo /home/radio-station/PI_FM/fm_transmitter/fm_transmitter -b 100  -f 87 /home/radio-station/Desktop/chubby-checker-the-twist-.wav")
        if song == 14:
            print("Playing Jackie Brenston Rocket 88")
            os.system("sudo /home/radio-station/PI_FM/fm_transmitter/fm_transmitter -b 100  -f 87 /home/radio-station/Desktop/Jackie-brenston-rocket-88.wav")
        if song == 15:
            print("Playing Nat King Cole Love")
            os.system("sudo /home/radio-station/PI_FM/fm_transmitter/fm_transmitter -b 100  -f 87 /home/radio-station/Desktop/Nat-King-Cole-Love.wav")
        if song == 16:
            print("Playing Bill Haley Rock around the clock")
            os.system("sudo /home/radio-station/PI_FM/fm_transmitter/fm_transmitter -b 100  -f 87 /home/radio-station/Desktop/rock-around-the-clock-bill-haley.wav")
        if song == 17:
            print("Playing Johnny Mathis Chances are")
            os.system("sudo /home/radio-station/PI_FM/fm_transmitter/fm_transmitter -b 100  -f 87 /home/radio-station/Desktop/johnny-mathis-chances-are.wav")
        if song == 18:
            print("Playing Willie Nelson On the road again")
            os.system("sudo /home/radio-station/PI_FM/fm_transmitter/fm_transmitter -b 100  -f 87 /home/radio-station/Desktop/willie-nelson-on-the-road-again-official-audio.wav")
        if song == 19:
            print("Playing Lewis LaMedica This is it")
            os.system("sudo /home/radio-station/PI_FM/fm_transmitter/fm_transmitter -b 100  -f 87 /home/radio-station/Desktop/this-is-it-as-heard-in-jimmy-and-judy.wav")
        if song == 20:
            print("Playing Johnny Cash Walbash Cannonball")
            os.system("sudo /home/radio-station/PI_FM/fm_transmitter/fm_transmitter -b 100  -f 87 /home/radio-station/Desktop/wabash-cannonball.wav")
        if song == 21:
            print("Playing Seth Macfarlane My Buick my love and I")
            os.system("sudo /home/radio-station/PI_FM/fm_transmitter/fm_transmitter -b 100  -f 87 /home/radio-station/Desktop/seth-macfarlane-ft-elizabeth-gillies-my-buick-my-love-and-i-ZXZm2prb8Eg.wav")
        if song == 22:
            print("Elvis Presley Hound dog")
            os.system("sudo /home/radio-station/PI_FM/fm_transmitter/fm_transmitter -b 100  -f 87 /home/radio-station/Desktop/elvis-presley-hound-dog-.wav")
        if song == 23:
            print("Joe Montgomery Bowling song")
            os.system("sudo /home/radio-station/PI_FM/fm_transmitter/fm_transmitter -b 100  -f 87 /home/radio-station/Desktop/joe-montgomery-bowling-song.wav")
        if song ==  24:
            print("Playing Anglo Tango The Fabulous Hudson Hornet")
            os.system("sudo /home/radio-station/PI_FM/fm_transmitter/fm_transmitter -b 100  -f 87/home/radio-station/Desktop/the-fabulous-hudson-hornet-j346xB4xfbI.wav")
            
        last_song = song
```

This program works fine. However I would like to be able to make the number "87" (which refers to the frequency to transmit on) a variable, so that I may easily change the frequency without retyping every command line. I tried to do this by adding the variable and modifying the terminal commands to this.

```
os.system("sudo /home/radio-station/PI_FM/fm_transmitter/fm_transmitter -b 100  -f",frequncy,"/home/radio-station/Desktop/chuck-berry-route-66.wav")
```

But I get this error

```
Activated
Choosing song
Song selected
PLaying Chuck Berry Route 66
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/radio-station/radio.py", line 33, in <module>
    os.system("sudo /home/radio-station/PI_FM/fm_transmitter/fm_transmitter -b 100  -f",frequncy,"/home/radio-station/Desktop/chuck-berry-route-66.wav")
TypeError: system() takes at most 1 argument (3 given)
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: you need to create the string (e.g. using some string formatting approach like the `.format` method, or f-strings, or even string conatenation with `+`) and *then* pass it as a single argument to the `os.system` command.

Comment: in any case, you probably shouldn't use `os.system` anyway

Comment: Prefer `subprocess.run()` instead of `os.system()`. Then you can give it all the arguments in a list, rather than formatting strings.

Comment: Also consider using a list of dictionaries rather than all those `if` statements to get the different parameters for each song.

Comment: "However I would like to be able to make the number "87" (which refers to the frequency to transmit on) a variable, so that I may easily change the frequency without retyping every command line. "  Why stop there?  The only actually different parameter is the filename.  All you really need is a list of filenames.

Comment: You have to produce a **single** string containing the complete command.